# Cannot raise button click event of another form

Tags: vb.net, button, instance, showdialog

I've two forms form1 and form2. form1 has button1 and form2 has button2.
What I want to achive is when I click on button1 form2 should be shown and button2 must get clicked. I've tried the below mentioned codes inside button1 click event.

```
form2.ShowDialog
form2.button2.PerformClick
```

Or

```
form2.ShowDialog
form2.button2_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
```

Or

```
Dim frm as New form2
frm.ShowDialog
frm.button2.PerformClick
```

Or

```
Dim frm as New form2
frm.ShowDialog
frm.button2_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
```

But none of the above mentioned methods are working. Only form2 is shown but button2 is not being clicked.

I've tried again by making 'button2_Click' event public but still it's not working.

Comment: Are you actually interested in pretending like the button was clicked, or do you just want to run some code that would also be called if the button was clicked? The button wasn't actually clicked, so you shouldn't make it seem like it was. Instead, you should make a separate method, for example `DoSomeStuff()` that is called when the button is clicked. You can make that method public and call it from `form1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that code STOPS in the current form when `ShowDialog()` is run.

One solution would be to create an instance of Form2 and wire up the [Shown()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?view=netcore-3.1) event, which gets run AFTER the form is displayed.

From there, you can click the button using the instance of the form you created:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f2 As New Form2
    AddHandler f2.Shown, Sub()
                             f2.Button2.PerformClick()
                         End Sub
    f2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Idle_Mind says, .ShowDialog() will stop the following code from working, so you have two ways around it.

- First invoke the event, and then show it as a dialog

  ```
  Dim frm as New form2
  frm.button2.PerformClick()
  frm.ShowDialog()
  ```
- Keep it as it is, but instead of showing it as a dialog, just show it.

  ```
  Dim frm as New form2
  frm.Show()
  frm.Visible = True
  frm.button2.PerformClick()
  ```